# C# read search result from textbox and show in listbox

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I'm doing a school project "a simple address book. The user input name, address, postnumber, city, telephone and email in textboxes. Then click the add button and saved in to a textfile and also show the new contact in listbox.

Right now I could search by name or city. I would like the user be able to search both name and city. How I should do that? Here is my code.

```
    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string searchTerm = textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower();


        List<Person> searchResult = People.FindAll(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm)
        || p.Postort.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm));


        listBoxPeople.Items.Clear();


        foreach (Person person in searchResult)
        {
            listBoxPeople.Items.Add(person.ToListBoxString());
        }

        if(searchResult.Count==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not found info! try again!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that the code that searches by name or city, or your attemt to search both by name and city?

Comment: my code right now the user can search by name or city But I would like to make the program be able to search both name and city same time for example, the user input Mark Newyork, then the program sum up all contact that name mark and Newyork.

Comment: You mean that the user inputs a name and a city separated by space? How about splitting the input on space and use the strings in the query that you have?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sticking to a single input text box for your search terms:

```
// Get an array of search terms... search for as many as you like
string[] searchTerm = textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower().Split(' ');

List<Person> searchResult = new List<Person>();

foreach (string term in searchTerm)
{
    searchResult.AddRange(People.FindAll(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(term)
        || p.Postort.ToLower().Contains(term)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (copy and paste ready):

```
private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string searchTerm = textBoxSearch.Text.ToLower();

        List<string> searchWords = new List<string>(searchTerm.Split(new char[] { ' ' }));
        List<Person> searchResult = new List<Person>();

        foreach (string word in searchWords)
        {
            searchResult.AddRange(People.FindAll(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(word)));
            searchResult.AddRange(People.FindAll(p => p.Postort.ToLower().Contains(word)));
        }

        listBoxPeople.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Person person in searchResult)
        {
            listBoxPeople.Items.Add(person.ToListBoxString());
        }

        if (searchResult.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not found info! try again!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the help. I got the error lin foreach-loop Contains Nooverload for method 'Contains' take 2 arguments. How should I fixed it?